# Submodules configuration for a submodule inside a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to clone the [toppra](https://github.com/hungpham2511/toppra) repository inside the [toppra-extension](https://gitlab.inria.fr/auctus-team/components/motion-planning/toppra_extensions) repo, and to do so I have my GitLab `.gitmodules` as follows:

```
[submodule "toppra_extensions"]
  path = toppra_extensions
  url = https://gitlab.inria.fr/auctus-team/components/motion-planning/toppra_extensions.git

[submodule "toppra_extensions/toppra"]
  path = toppra_extensions/topra
  url = https://github.com/hungpham2511/toppra.git
```

the problem is that: `git submodule sync` is not synchronizing the [toppra](https://github.com/hungpham2511/toppra) submodule, can you please tell me what should I change to make the synchronization automated using `.gitmodules`? thanks in advance.

Comment: @phd can you please elaborate more, what should I change in the `.gitmodules` to automate the clone/pull process?

Comment: @phd I have tried `[submodule "toppra"]  path = toppra_extensions/topra  url = https://github.com/hungpham2511/toppra.git`, but it didn't work also!

Comment: `toppra_extensions` already [has `toppra` as a submodule](https://gitlab.inria.fr/auctus-team/components/motion-planning/toppra_extensions/-/blob/a632bdbb7b592e1bc423e7502acb159d6ecf611c/.gitmodules). Remove `[submodule "toppra_extensions/toppra"]` from the superproject's `.gitmodules`. Use `git clone --recurse-submodules` to clone, `git submodule sync --recursive` and `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toppra_extensions` already [has `toppra` as a submodule](https://gitlab.inria.fr/auctus-team/components/motion-planning/toppra_extensions/-/blob/a632bdbb7b592e1bc423e7502acb159d6ecf611c/.gitmodules).

To properly clone your project remove `[submodule "toppra_extensions/toppra"]` from the superproject's .gitmodules:

```
git config -f .gitmodules remove-section submodule.toppra_extensions/toppra
```

Use `git clone --recurse-submodules` to clone, `git submodule sync --recursive` and `git submodule update --init --recursive` to update.